# Is WebBrowser's open_new deprecated?

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a new google chrome window using `webbrowser` controller.

```
import webbrowser

CHROME_PATH = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'
browser = webbrowser.get(CHROME_PATH)
browser.open_new("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

This will open a chrome window (if there is no chrome already running), how ever when I run the script again, it will keep opening in a new tab and not in a new window (even if I change the URL I want to open).

I wonder whether new tab is being enforced by the browser or it is an issue in the `webbrowser` controler.

Is there any other way to control the URL opening? (new window or tab)

System Information:

```
macOs Big Sur 11.3
Python 3.7.4
Chrome 96.0.4664.55
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an issue of the webbrowser module or something being enforced by Chrome but this issue also occurs on my Windows machine running python 3.9.6. There are more posts here on SO about this issue. As a workaround I use the snippet of code shown below (tested on my m1 mac running Big Sur). This makes sure a new Chrome window will be opened every time you run it. Explanation what the chrome_path arguments do can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305901/is-it-possible-to-open-a-new-chrome-browser-window-from-terminal-with-multiple-s).

```
import webbrowser

chrome_path = 'open -na /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --new-window %s'
url="http://www.yahoo.com"
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new(url)
```